# How to design a complex questionnarie database

Tags: database

Der experts

I am trying to model a complex questionnaire following this database model:

http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/questionnaires_complex/index.htm

I am having a little bit of difficulty understanding the model.

Let us say that i have a question which takes a Ranked Answer from 1-5

```
[Table]
Question_types
type_code = 1
type_description = "Ranked Answer"

[Table]
Questions
question_number = 1
question_type = 1
question_wording = "How much do you like lasagne?"
```

I want the question ranked from 1-5 - in which table should i put the possible rankings?

Thanks in advance
Nanek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, I suppose?

```
[Table]
Ranked_Answers

question_number = 1
answer_rank = 1
answer_wording = "Love"

question_number = 1
answer_rank = 2
answer_wording = "Like"

question_number = 1
answer_rank = 3
answer_wording = "Indifferent"

question_number = 1
answer_rank = 4
answer_wording = "Dislike"

question_number = 1
answer_rank = 5
answer_wording = "Hate"
```

And thus `question_number` would be a foreign key here, assuming it's the primary key in your `Questions` table.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't a ranked question just a specific type of multiple choice question? So your rankings have to be put into the table "Multiple_Choice_Questions", with "choice number" receiving your 1 to 5 and "choice wording" your rank-specific text (like "worst" to "best").

Comment: How could i in a good and dynamic way add these ranking answers to multiple questions, without having to write the wordings over again?

Comment: If you have many questions with the same wordings, define a table containing such sets of wordings and put only a foreign key in the questions table that points to the required set of answers.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason that you don't just save the value from the code? IE. have a radio button set in HTML with different values, and then store the value selected by the user?